# XCode 4.2: Where has "Value Transformer Name" gone for Core Data attribute type 'Transformable'?

Tags: xcode, core-data, uiimage, nsvaluetransformer

I'm creating an `NSValueTransformer` subclass to convert a `UIImage` to/from an `NSData` to allow insertion/retrieval to/from a Core Data SQLite database. However, after selecting Attribute type `Transformable` in the Xcode 4.2 integrated Data Model Editor, there is no `Value Transformer Name` property to specify which transformer class should be used.

Does anyone know where this has moved to? It was there in earlier versions of Xcode.

Many thanks!

Comment: I could change my question to Xcode 4.x and it would remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Xcode 4.1:

[image]

The (value transformer) **Name** box is right below **Attribute Type**.

By the way, I bind an `NSImageView`'s Value binding to this attribute, and it works as desired, even without specifying a value transformer.

Comment: My bad, I assumed it wasn't in any 4.x but it must just be 4.2 which as you say is NDA. Consequently I've made a post in the Apple Developer Forum; presumably it's just a beta interface omission. Will set via an NSAttributeDescription on my NSEntityDescription for now. Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell me what should I type in the "Name" text field?

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649653/core-data-what-should-i-type-in-the-value-transformer-name