# Core data: What should I type in the "Value Transformer Name"

Tags: xcode, core-data

I want to store UIImage in core data and use the default value transformer. Apple doc says:

> If you are using the model editor in Xcode, select Transformable in
>   the attribute’s Type popup and type the name in the Value Transformer
>   Name text field.

Type what name exactly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to refer you to a previous answer. Look at the comment to!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909082

As you can see, if you are targeting iOS 5+, you should be able to just mark it as transformable and be good. Otherwise, you're going to have to implement a subclass of NSValueTransformer, and pass in the name of that class.

Comment: I saw that post before I post mine. It's about subclassing the transformer, of which I do not intend. You are suggesting "Leave it blank",right?

Comment: Absolutely. I made a quick little sample app for iOS 5.0, and it worked just fine. I agree, it does seem a little weird to not put anything in there, but you're fine. Here it is, if you're interested: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25530123/CoreDataImageExample.zip